# Does the .append and .insert function edit objects inserted into lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
oldrow = [1]

for i in range(5): 
  finaloutputlist.append(oldrow)
  print(oldrow)
  
  oldrow.append(0)
  oldrow.insert(0,0)
  
  j = i + 1
  newrow = []
  for i in range(len(oldrow) -1):
    #print(oldrow[i])
    newrow.append(oldrow[i] + oldrow [i+1])
  
  oldrow = newrow

print(finaloutputlist)
```

When I run the above code, I get an output of

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
[[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 0], [0, 1, 4, 6, 4, 1, 0]]
```

There when I print "oldrow", I get exactly the array that I want to append onto my list of arrays in called finaloutputlist .But appending that same oldrow keeps netting me the final output line. For some reason the 0s that I add after updating my finaloutputlist seem to be making their way onto the list.

Comment: `finaloutputlist.append(oldrow)` doesn't append a copy of `oldrow`, it appends *`oldrow` itself* - any subsequent modifications to that list are visible in `finaloutputlist`.  This can be fixed via `finaloutputlist.append(oldrow.copy())` or `finaloutputlist.append(oldrow[:])`.

Comment: or `import copy; finaloutputlist.append(copy.deepcopy(oldrow))` depending on your data structures. But since you're list only contain `int`, standard copy should be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @jasonharper,

```
finaloutputlist.append(oldrow.copy())
```

worked amazing, no extra imports needed